# Visual Studio: run in debug mode from different folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Good morning.

I wrote a command line *.exe app (call it `myapp.exe`) that accept some arguments and make his work basically using input and output files.
This app is called by a 3rd party application, pretending that `myapp.exe` is in his `\root\bin` folder.
Input and output files are difficult to replicate for tests, so I would find much easier do something like this:

- Build my solution
- Using some `PostBuildEvents`, deploy assemblies in calling app's `\root\bin` folder on my disk
- Launch Visual Studio in debug mode, **but using assemblies and `*.pdb` deployed in `\root\bin` folder**

Is that a thing I can do?
I know [Visual Studio Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) function, but `myapp.exe` is not a process I can attach to.

Some ideas? :)

Comment: how you pass argument for application in debug mode.

Comment: Typical command is something like this: bin\myapp.exe -a:other\subfolder\inputFile.txt; caller app writes inputFile just before call myapp.exe.

Comment: I am trying to make sure I understand.  Are you trying to get it to launch 'myapp.exe' or the third part application?

Comment: I want to launch myapp.exe in debug, using Visual Studio step-by-step functionality, but I want to launch it using assemblies in X:\root\bin folder: I hope I've explained it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it should be as easy as right-clicking the project in question on go to the debug tab, you should see "Start External Program" option.  Browse to your \root\bin folder and select myapp.exe and you should have the version of myapp that you deployed in the post build event run.

Comment: Weel, \root\bin\myapp.exe stars, but not in debug (step-by-step) mode :)

Comment: Try right clicking the project and going to debug->step into new instance.